# C# MD5 Antivirus program. Selected folder returning empty string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, md5

The source code is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BD9fdwyYq-WBmA3vtyt3htHPjAYwDUqV)

My problem is when the user opens a folder, the only thing that can read the selected path is a message box; nothing else can read the path. I've tried printing it to a list box with no success, just a blank string, and the md5 hash is always blank.

Also, by the way, this is written with C#, Visual Studio 2017, Windows Forms, and .NET Framework Version 4.5.

The goal of this program is to read a list of strings off of a text file and compare them to the md5 hash of the file to detect a virus.

If anyone can find a way to fix my problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

This is for self-entertainment only. I have no intention of selling this program.

Comment: I have tried your program and it worked, It does not redraw the list box until it finishes "scanning" though, this is why you might have an impression that it ""can't read the path".

Comment: Oh. Does the md5 hash output in the label?

Comment: @rs232 Also I did notice that. I don't think it lets you draw anything. Except during those periods when it outputs the bad hash in the first listbox. Good to know!

Comment: Which label? I don't see if you set any label's text to any kind of md5 hash in your code.

Comment: Oh. Right. I put in the current md5 hash label and then an empty label below it. I removed the code which updated the label

Comment: @rs232 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, under load during scanning, the listboxes and labels could not update their graphics, giving the impression that the variable that contained the string was blank.